# How to setup a complicated 'IsList' parameter in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm looking at this link:

[Actions and parameters | Dialogflow Documentation | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#lists)

Where it explains 'List parameters' it uses these examples:

> - "I want apples"
> - "I want apples and oranges"
> - "I want apples, oranges, and bananas"

Then I was wondering if it's possible to set up a 'List parameter' to handle something like this:

> "I want 7 apples, 8 oranges and 12 bananas"

So you'd have a sort of Key - Value pair list.

Pseudo code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> fruitList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

KeyValuePair<string, int> applesItem = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("apples", 7);
KeyValuePair<string, int> orangesItem = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("oranges", 8);
KeyValuePair<string, int> bananasItem = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("bananas", 12);

fruitList.Add(applesItem);
fruitList.Add(orangesItem);
fruitList.Add(bananasItem);
```

So, in dialogflow, the `$FruitList` parameter would be something like the Key - Value pair list `fruitList` above.

The number part should then match with the `@sys.cardinal` entity. And the fruit part should match to a custom entity `@Fruits` with a bunch of fruits in it.

Pseudo code: `List<KeyValuePair<@sys.cardinal, @Fruits>>`

How can I make an 'Intent' in Dialogflow that can do this?
Is it possible?

Help / Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if you could get dialogflow return a key value pair object, but using composite entities you can create an entity which consists of an amount (number) and a fruit (fruit entity). You could call this composite entity order and make that a list in the parameters in your intent. When you enter

"I want 7 apples, 8 oranges and 12 bananas"

You should get a list with 3 order entities ( 7 apples, 8 oranges, 12 bananas)

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-developer#developer_composite

Comment: :) This is really helpful. Thanks for the feedback. I've one question on 'Developer Composite Entities'. I see in the example in the link: "@sys.number:steps". I understand the "@sys.number" part is the 'Entity Name', but what is the part after the colon; the "....:steps" part? When I make a 'Composite Entity' do I need that part? What is the effect of the part after the colon? @Jordi

Comment: @sys.number is the type, steps is the name of the parameter. So it will come in your webhook as parameter.steps. So if you change it to what you want, make sure to also change it in your webhook

Comment: Thank you :). Sad Pika @Jordi. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I've created new problems for myself here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889804/how-to-setup-a-more-complicated-islist-parameter-in-dialogflow @Jordi