# How to setup a more complicated 'IsList' parameter in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've asked this question previously:

[How to setup a complicated 'IsList' parameter in Dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855562/how-to-setup-a-complicated-islist-parameter-in-dialogflow)

In there I had this example:

> "I want 7 apples, 8 oranges and 12 bananas"

So by setting up a 'Developer Composite Entity' that looks like this:

```
@sys.cardinal:Amount @Fruits:Fruit
```

I was able to solve my problem.

In there I'm using the `@sys.cardinal` system entity and my own custom `@Fruits` entity, which has a bunch of fruits in it.

I'm now looking for a way to handle examples like this:

> "I want green apples, small oranges and cavendish bananas"

I then tried to make a new 'Developer Composite Entity' as follows:

```
@sys.any:Description @Fruits:Fruit
```

Now I'm using the `@sys.any` system entity instead of `@sys.cardinal`, but then I get this error:

[image: Dialogflow Entity Error]

> "Do not use @sys.any in entities."

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Help / Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use "sys.any"

1. Create a custom entity named "fruit-description" and add values like "small,cavendish,green etc." as many as you expect and also tick the "Allow automated expansions" Checkbox ,so any unexpected property which you have not mentioned is likely to be detected as a property.
2. Also train agent after adding new utterances carrying this new entitiy "fruit-description".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What is the reason Dialogflow doesn't allow sys.any in Entities? It's also odd the wording of the error. Why say: "Do not use sys.any in entities."? Why not say something like: "Error. Cannot use sys.any in entities."?